# How to include skins/lightgray in tinyMCE grunt bundle

Tags: gruntjs, tinymce-4

Pretty simple, I want to run single command and get all necessary plugins, css and fonts inside one minified tinymce.min.js file

After running:

```
grunt bundle --themes=modern --plugins=table,paste
```

I got minified tinymce with plugins, but WITHOUT skins/lightgray which include css, fonts, images

How can I do that?

Comment: no luck so far?

Comment: just added my answer

Answer (score 0):

found answer by myself,

added extra param for skin_url:

```
  skin_url: './unpackaged-dependencies/tinymce/skins/lightgray'
```

And include original tinyMCE CSS and fonts

[image]

so tinymce.full.min.js and skins package should be on the same level

[image]